# "Just" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

Consider the following sentence:

> I don't know.

Easily, the Spanish for this would be:

> No sé.

How can one place some stress on the "not knowing" part of this sentence...maybe when one is a little annoyed while saying it? In English, one could say:

> I just don't know!

Is there any way to translate the sense of "just" in Spanish in this context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I just don't know* could be translated to this most of the times:

```
Simplemente no lo sé.
```

Also *sencillamente*, same as simplemente.

It is more or less neutral, you can use it in many context, probably in all of them. But depending on the context (mostly the question that is being answered and the mood of the respondent) other forms could be more expressive:

```
No lo sé, y ya está.
[Te he dicho] ¡que no lo sé!
```

A lot of stress here, probably it means *stop asking me or I'll get angry*.

Comment: Does `no lo se, y ya esta` mean "I don't know and that's that"?

Comment: @0x499602D2, here _y ya está_ means that *you* won't add anything else (and you are probably annoyed), or maybe that *there is* nothing else to say, so I would translate it to _period / full stop_, or maybe _and that's all_.

Answer (score 8):

Some other usual alternatives, to add to Lucas' answer:

```
  De verdad, no sé.
  ¡Te digo que no lo sé!
  No sé, y punto. (=y basta).
```

Answer (score 3):

The word *just* has no straightforward translation to Spanish. The correct translation depends on the sentence.

In this case, I would suggest *no tengo ni idea*, at least in Spain. This expression begs the listener to stop asking. It can also convey annoyance, though not necessarily.

Comment: Isn't "no tengo ni idea" a straightforward translation for "I have no idea". I don't see how this conveys any further emphasis as "No sé" and "I don't know", respectively.

Comment: *No tengo ni idea* means, more or less, *I don't know at all*, so it is more emphatic than just *No sé*. Other suggested constructions, in my opinion, are unusual or convey a strong annoyance (rather than being *maybe a little annoyed*, os OP said).

Comment: @em1 it means more like "I haven't a clue" which is definitely stronger than simply "I don't know"

Answer (score 2):

- Sencillamente no lo sé
- Simplemente no lo sé
- No tengo ni la más mínima idea
- No tengo ni la más remota idea